# Correct my GPS Aquaris M10

Tags: ubuntu-touch, aquaris, bq, gps, m10

OK, so here's my problem: My bq Aquaris m10 is convinced that I am somewhere in Kansas, even though I live in the California bay area.  This is a difference of a little over 2,000 miles!  I've never been to Kansas.  I'm sure it's a nice place, but I've never been there, and it's not like I could have made a wrong turn to end up there, and yet no matter what I do, or how often I reset my device... It's still convinced that I'm in Kansas!?!  The Date, and Time are correct for my timezone, but the location of my device according to my GPS I'm somehow in Kansas.

I swear to God that I'm in California.  Could someone please tell me how to convince my tablet of that?

Comment: How long have you let it sit to try to find your location? Also, is it connected to WiFi  and/or data?

Comment: Funny thing, it fixed itself last night.  It's connected to WiFi and GPS, there's no data on the Aquaris.  I'm glad to be in California (no offense to Kansas), and I'm glad that my tablet agrees that I'm here, but I would still like to know how to recalibrate my GPS in case this happens again.

Comment: I don't think you can. Of course, reboots can work magic.